# How to remove tags and html entities in php

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove all the tags (but keeps img, sub, sup) and styles from my code and also remove all the html entities (but keeps `&amp;` (&) and `&copy;` (©)) using REGEX. but I don't know how it's use can any one guide me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this coming from a text input box from a form on your own site?

Comment: Have a look at `strip_tags()`, you can even allow tags you want to keep.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the string you have in input and what you want in output, also if possible can you provide the bit of code where that logic is ?

Answer (score -1):

For PHP take a look at the php docs at http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php

For Regexp in general check http://www.regular-expressions.info/

For live testing take a look at https://regex101.com/, it is a really good testing tool and explains the whole expression piece by piece.

As you want to keep your styles, strip_tags won't take you the whole way.

Comment: This is not an answer to the problem, is it?

Comment: Maybe I understood it wrong, I think he wanted to remove certain tags / styles from his "code" which I assumed is the html code he generates with PHP. He can do this with regular expressions very nicely, so why is it not an answer?

Answer (score -1):

Try filter_var
You can see more filters on: 
http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

```
echo filter_var('coco <p>&copy;&amp;</p>',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```